# Automatic table height with collectionView content - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

The hierarchy looks like this:

- Table View
- - Table View Cell
- - - Collection View
- - - - Collection View Cell

The Collection View content is loaded by ajax json.

I want the table to adjust the height after loading the data.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make dynamically changing UICollectionView like this

```
import UIKit

class DynamicCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    }
}
```

and put this collectionView in UITablaViewCell. After that you should write in your viewDidLoad() method

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 //height which one you want, it does not matter
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

This is all. I hope this will help solve your problem.